# Implicit Intent with user-specified action

Tags: android, action, activitynotfoundexception, android-implicit-intent

I'm experimenting, specifying my own action for use in an implicit intent.  In a single package, I define two activities.  ActivityTwo is to be called from onClick() in ActivityOne, using an implicit intent with an action "course.labs.activitylab.MY_ACTION".  But I haven't been able to make it work.

In strings.xml:

```
<string name="myfunnystring">course.labs.activitylab.MY_ACTION</string>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityTwo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_two" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="@string/myfunnystring" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In onClick() in the OnClickListener() in onCreate() in ActivityOne.java:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(getString(R.string.myfunnystring));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION);
            startActivity(intent);
```

The program crashes in the emulator, and I find this in the logcat window:

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=course.labs.activitylab.MY_ACTION flg=0x8 }

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the default category to your intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="course.labs.activitylab.MY_ACTION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I think you can't use a string resource in the action name.

Comment: That fixes it.  Okay, so I made two mistakes. I used a string resource in the action name in the filter.  IDK why that shouldn't work, and if it won't work, IDK why it isn't detected at build-time.  And I failed to give a category to the intent filter.  Thank you, karaokyo.

Comment: These two requirements are explained at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html